# Why is Homebrew lynx configuration not in my home directory

Tags: homebrew

When installing lynx with Homebrew, the primary configuration (according to the lynx option screen) is at a long, version-specific path (thus the path will change every time a new version is installed):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1/etc/lynx.cfg
```

Why isn't the default configuration placed in a normal place like:

```
~/.lynxrc
```

Comment: Isn't `/usr/local/Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1/etc/lynx.cfg` linked to `/usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg`?

Comment: @fd0: You're right! I didn't notice that. However Lynx shows the long path in the option screen, which is confusing (and ugly!) It's linked this direction: `/usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg -> ../Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1/etc/lynx.cfg`, so if you edit `/usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg`, I assume your changes will be gone when you install the next version of Lynx. Do you know what have they been thinking when they decided to do it like this? Is there some user-friendly logic behind the design that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's by design. According to the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) homepage:

> Homebrew won’t install files outside its prefix and you can place a Homebrew installation wherever you like.

According to the [lynx man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx) page:

> **LYNX_CFG**            This variable, if set, will override the default
>   location and name of  the  global  configuration  file  (normally,
>                          lynx.cfg) that was defined by the LYNX_CFG_FILE constant in the userdefs.h file, during installation.

In some linux distribution, the constant `LYNX_CFG_FILE` in set to `~/.lynxrc` (as I remember) but in Homebrew  this constant is left to its default value. You can check it with `brew edit lynx`. If you want to change the location of the lynx configuration file, you have, as you tell, to set:

```
export LYNX_CFG=~/.lynxrc
```

Comment: Aha! They should have mentioned the configuration files specifically, because this is not expected by the user. However, I think you are wrong about simply adding `~/.lynxrc`. I tried this, and it wasn't until I did `export LYNX_CFG=~/.lynxrc` that this file took effect. Does it work for you without the environment variable?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I've modified my answer.